# Simplify TableLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a problem with an android-studio-warning. It's about the TableLayout I used to put two buttons side by side. Android-Studio said that 'TableRow' layout or its 'TableLayout' parent was useless. So I asked me how to simplify this code:

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:stretchColumns="1,0"
            android:layout_below="@id/dialog_cp_playlistname"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TableRow >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dialog_cp_cancel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="25dp"
                android:text="@string/object_cancel"
                android:textColor="@color/white_70"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dialog_cp_next"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="25dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:text="@string/object_next"
                android:textColor="@color/accent_color"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to do this.

I am looking forward to a reply.

Comment: Quick fix: Remove the `TableRow`. Proper fix: Need to know the rest of the layout.

Comment: Thank you. The hole layout is: Relativ Layout->TableLayout(is in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is use `weight`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Happy coding!